# Pandas Dataframe '[nan nan nan ... nan nan nan] not found in axis'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Receiving this error
`'[nan nan nan ... nan nan nan] not found in axis'`
When trying to drop columns from a dataframe if the value is zero

```
train_df.head()

external_company_id company_name    email_domain    mx_record   ... 
NaN                 Expresstext     expresstext.net unknown expresstext.net ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
NaN                 Jobox           jobox.ai    unknown www.jobox.ai    ... 17.0    -31.0   9.0 30.0
NaN                 Relola          relola.com  unknown home.relola.com ... 5.0 -25.0   5.0 

train_df.drop(train_df[train_df['total_funding'] == float(0)].index, inplace = True, axis=0) 

'[nan nan nan ... nan nan nan] not found in axis'
```

What would be causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

I learned that pandas automatically uses the first column as the index for read_csv.
Because my first column was empty every index somehow ended up being NaN as seen in the question above.

I ran these two lines of code to create a new index and fill it.

```
train_df.index.name = 'id'
train_df.index = [x for x in range(1, len(train_df.values)+1)]
```

Then the former error disapeared

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
train_df.drop(...)
```

try:

```
train_df = train_df[train_df[train_df['total_funding'] != float(0)]
```